# Reading VRAM data

Tags: c++, graphics

I'm trying to make a C++ program to capture everything that's being displayed on screen.

After lots of Googling what I found were methods that captured a particular window,
or a particular program screen, or some program's particular buffer. 
Somehow I got some codes that can capture the screen but they didn't show the mouse or video.

Then I came to know that only way to capture everything regardless of what's being displayed is to get access to video RAM on the graphics card (mine is integrated one).
But I can't find any way to read the VRAM data.

I know that VRAM holds each single pixel that goes to the monitor. That's what I want my program to read and read it fast to get about 30fps.
I need the raw bitmap that is stored in VRAM just before it's converted to analog.

Edit:-  I just found this sdl and pixel toaster library... they can read so called frame buffer .... will this be of any use also opengl has a method called getPixels()  can this read the buffer data of all applications regardless of what is running??

Comment: The VRAM is protected by the OS. You'll need to start by telling us which OS this will run on.

Comment: Questions with "I know that ..." are most often wrong about that fact.

Comment: Best solution is to capture the screen without the mouse and then get the mouse coordinates and draw it yourself for whatever purpose.

Comment: If you want to capture video, have you considered the RIAA? They're bound to be interested in your activity.

Comment: @jli jli is right, afaik all the VNC implementations do it that way. By the way you could look into some OSS VNC implementations like TightVnc to see how they do it. The caveat being that you still ask the OS and it can draw stuff that you won't capture like the admin privilege dialogues.

Answer (score 0):

With hardware overlay, there might not actually be an image that contains the screen image and mouse cursor.

The code that captures the screen without the mouse cursor IS reading the VRAM.

Comment: Is this really an answer to the question? It seems more like it should have been a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you'll have to develop a kernel-mode driver for Windows as it's only from the OS kernel you can directly access everything. It's not an easy task though and if you try to sign your driver, chances are Microsoft will refuse. Or if they sign it, they will probably soon revoke the signature. In short, you'll have problems distributing your driver because of the associated legal issues.

Another option would be to find an open-source PC emulator where Windows works and the videos in question play and hack it to get access to the VM's memory. Same legal stuff.

Other than that I don't think there's a guaranteed way of getting all the data (besides hacking into the hardware or simply capturing the screen on camera, of course).

Comment: This is just wrong.  Video memory is accessed via existing API's - DirectX and OpenGL are two of the better ones (GDI can do it, but not at speeds approaching 30fps as the OP has requested).

Comment: @freefallr: This is not wrong. Think of the features prohibiting you from copying sensitive on-screen data using regular APIs. How about that?

Comment: "Most likely you'll have to develop a kernel-mode driver for Windows as it's only from the OS kernel you can directly access everything" - this is what I consider wrong.  You have access to the VRAM directly, through the aforementioned APIs.